# Using send_file weird file naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails: V6.0.0

I'm using `send_file` to send a file from the server to the client. Filename on the server is correct and send accordingly.

Code:

```
send_file service.file_path, filename: "test.csv", type: "text/csv", disposition: "attachment"
```

When it arrives on the client the filename has completely changed to:

```
test.csv_; filename_=UTF-8''test.cs
```

Anyone has an idea why this happens? Or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: a bit more of code will help

Comment: That's the only code there is. A CSV file is on the server and is being send with the code above. On rails 5 this was working properly. I updated to 6.0 and this problem came up.

Answer (score 0):

this just started happening to me in Rails 7. I found and reopened this related issue on rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39772.

Apparently they were unable to reproduce the bug, so it could be browser specific.

The suggested and tested workaround is to omit filename and set it directly in the disposition header. In your case it would look like this:

```
send_file service.file_path, type: "text/csv", disposition: "attachment; filename=test.csv"
```